# I can not get Json ipx800 swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

I can not find the value "AN1 - AN2 -AN3 where am I wrong? anyone can help me. thanks

this is json that my hardware provides me:

```
{  
"product" : "IPX800_V3" , 
"AN1" : 0 , 
"AN2" : 0 , 
"AN3" : 240 , 
"AN4" : 0 , 
"AN5" : 0 , 
"AN6" : 0 , 
"AN7" : 0 , 
"AN8" : 0 , 
"AN9" : 0 , 
"AN10" : 0 , 
"AN11" : 0 , 
"AN12" : 0 , 
"AN13" : 0 , 
"AN14" : 0 , 
"AN15" : 0 , 
"AN16" : 0 
}
```

This is the code of my application where I try to get the value:

```
@IBOutlet weak var info: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var analog3: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    getipxData("http://192.168.1.201/api/xdevices.json?cmd=30")
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
func getipxData(urlstring: String) {
    let url = NSURL(string: urlstring)
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) { (data, response, error) in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
           self.setlabels(data)
        })

    }
    task.resume()
}

func setlabels(ipxData: NSData){
    var jsonError: NSError?

    let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(ipxData, options: nil, error: &jsonError) as! NSDictionary

    if let name = json["product"] as? String {
        info.text = name

        }
    if let ana1 = json["AN3"] as? String{
        analog3.text = ana1

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
@IBOutlet weak var info: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var analog3: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    getipxData("http://192.168.1.201/api/xdevices.json?cmd=30")
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
func getipxData(urlstring: String) {
    let url = NSURL(string: urlstring)
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) { (data, response, error) in

      if error == nil {
          dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
             self.setlabels(data)
         })
     } else {
        println("error occured-\(error)")
     }
}

 task.resume()

}

func setlabels(ipxData: NSData){
    var jsonError: NSError?
    println(ipxData)
    let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(ipxData, options: .MutableLeaves, error: &jsonError) as! [String: AnyObject]

    if let name = json["product"] as? String {
        info.text = name

        }
    if let ana1 = json["AN3"] as? String{
        analog3.text = ana1
    }
}
```

If value for AN3 is Int do as below.

```
if let value1 = json["AN3"] as? Int {
      analog3.text = "\(value1)"
}
```

Similarly if value is `Double`, replace `Int` with `Double`.

Comment: is not highlighted" .MutableLeaves, "

Comment: Are you getting values? MutableLeaves  - Specifies that leaf strings in the JSON object graph are created as instances of NSMutableString.

Comment: I do not get any value, you could better explain .MutableLeaves
I'm sorry but I'm new in Xcode . Thanks for availability

Comment: Add this line println(ipxData) in setlabels function to check wether response has value or not.

Comment: i get :<7b227072 6f647563 74223a22 49505838 30305f56 33222c22 414e3122 3a302c22 414e3222 3a302c22 414e3322 3a323236 2c22414e 34223a30 2c22414e 35223a30 2c22414e 36223a30 2c22414e 37223a30 2c22414e 38223a30 2c22414e 39223a30 2c22414e 3130223a 302c2241 4e313122 3a302c22 414e3132 223a302c 22414e31 33223a30 2c22414e 3134223a 302c2241 4e313522 3a302c22 414e3136 223a307d>

Comment: Also print the json. println(json)

Comment: [AN5: 0, AN10: 0, AN9: 0, AN14: 0, AN6: 0, AN16: 0, AN4: 0, AN7: 0, AN11: 0, product: IPX800_V3, AN8: 0, AN3: 226, AN15: 0, AN2: 0, AN13: 0, AN1: 0, AN12: 0]

Comment: the "product" on my label appears "PX800_V3", AN ... but do not give me value

Comment: I have to get this  "AN3" : 240

Comment: let myValue = json["AN3"] as! Int

Comment: perfect with println (myValue) I get the value.
now as the mold on the label? thanks

Comment: because when I try to:  let myValue = json["AN3"] as! Int    Analog3.text = myvalue //me error string

Comment: @MarcoBagnarelli, this is wrote at the bottom of my answer. Use this also analog3.text = String(myValue)